# why they use this in GetWindowRect function

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

```
        // Get the size of the window to capture
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
        GetWindowRect(handle, ref rect);

        // GetWindowRect returns Top/Left and Bottom/Right, so fix it
        rect.Width = rect.Width - rect.X;
        rect.Height = rect.Height - rect.Y;
```

I am not very good at English, but I'm very interested in coding in c#, so sorry if I post a stupid question.
Anyway, I read about   `GetWindowRect(handle, ref rect);` and I know that this function will return `Top/Left` and `Bottom/Right` of the handle to the "rect". But why does this code need to be fixed the problem by

```cpp
    rect.Width = rect.Width - rect.X;
    
    rect.Height = rect.Height - rect.Y;
```

- What is the point? doesn't `GetWindowRect` already return the position of top left and to right already?
- Why do they have to fix it?

Comment: Just a bad [DllImport] declaration, using Rectangle instead of RECT.  So they had to fix the geometry afterwards.

Comment: Can I just they that they're lazy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whoever defined the `Rectangle` structure in your codebase didn't follow the names on the structure in the C header files. The [RECT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windef/ns-windef-rect) structure has `top`, `left`, `bottom` and `right` members, which hold the screen coordinates of the rectangle.

Your code is "cheating" by grabbing the coordinates and then remapping the `bottom` and `right` members to be the height and width.

Comment: thanks you very much, Sean! 
is it have to do with
"In conformance with conventions for the RECT structure, the bottom-right coordinates of the returned rectangle are exclusive. In other words, the pixel at (right, bottom) lies immediately outside the rectangle."

Comment: Oh now, I get it. Thanks again Sean. after I read your post for 2-3times. I solve my curiosity. this mean a lot to me. I am smarter because of you Thanks xD

Comment: @Sean - `Whoever defined the Rectangle structure in your codebase` - sarcasm? It's the same Midrosoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle?view=netcore-3.1 :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me what you are asking but
You can find the API information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowrect)

You will find that `GetWindowRect` returns only `boolean` but not a `RECT`

However, it writes to the second parameter to set a `RECT` structure.

After they finally modify the value they have retrieve of `rect` obtained from `GetWindowrect()`.

Comment: I see, Thanks you very much.